# Angular2 creating logs in an external file

Tags: logging, angular

I am using RC4 version of Angular2. (Since the final version released recently and My application needs to be released sooner) I need to create a log file at an external location where all the logs from the application can get saved and in case of any error we can simply refer to the log file.

Please suggest how can i achieve this keeping in mind i am using RC4 Angular2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Angular2 related. 
You can't write files from the browser. 
You need a server that provides an API where you can post your log content, to be stored to a file by the server.

Comment: Thanks. I understood it now.